# difference between input.read and input.read(array, offset, length)

Tags: java, bufferedinputstream

I'm trying to understand how inputstreams work. The following block of code is one of the many ways to read data from a text file:-

```
File file = new File("./src/test.txt");
InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream (new FileInputStream(file));
int data = 0;

while (data != -1)   (-1 means we reached the end of the file)
 {
     data = input.read(); //if a character was read, it'll be turned to a bite and we get the integer representation of it so a is 97 b is 98
     System.out.println(data + (char)data); //this will print the numbers followed by space then the character
 }

input.close();
```

Now to use `input.read(byte, offset, length)` i have this code. I got it from [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=245)

```
File file = new File("./src/test.txt");
InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream (new FileInputStream(file));
int totalBytesRead = 0, bytesRemaining, bytesRead;
byte[] result = new byte[ ( int ) file.length()];

while ( totalBytesRead < result.length )
 {
     bytesRemaining = result.length - totalBytesRead;
     bytesRead = input.read ( result, totalBytesRead, bytesRemaining );
     if ( bytesRead > 0 )
      totalBytesRead = totalBytesRead + bytesRead;

     //printing integer version of bytes read
     for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
      System.out.print(result[i] + " ");

     System.out.println();

     //printing character version of bytes read
     for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
      System.out.print((char)result[i]);
 }

input.close();
```

I'm assuming that based on the name `BYTESREAD`, this read method is returning the number of bytes read. In the documentation, it says that the function will try to read as many as possible. So there might be a reason why it wouldn't.

**My first question is: What are these reasons?**

I could replace that entire while loop with one line of code: `input.read(result, 0, result.length)`

I'm sure the creator of the article thought about this. It's not about the output because I get the same output in both cases. So there has to be a reason. At least one. What is it?

Comment: Short answer? You might be trying to read 20 bytes, but only 10 are left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation of `read(byte[],int,int`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) says that it:

- Reads **up to len** bytes of data.
- An **attempt** is made to read **as many as** len bytes
- **A smaller number may be read**.

Since we are working with files that are right there in our hard disk, it seems reasonable to expect that the **attempt** will read the whole file, but `input.read(result, 0, result.length)` is not guaranteed to read the whole file (it's not said anywhere in the documentation). Relying in undocumented behaviors is a source for bugs when the undocumented behavior change.

For instance, the file stream may be implemented differently in other JVMs, some OS may impose a limit on the number of bytes that you may read at once, the file may be located in the network, or you may later use that piece of code with another implementation of stream, which doesn't behave in that way.

Alternatively, if you are reading the whole file in an array, perhaps you could use [`DataInputStream.readFully`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readFully%28byte%5B%5D%29)

About the loop with `read()`, it reads a single byte each time. That reduces performance if you are reading a big chunk of data, since each call to `read()` will perform several tests (has the stream ended? etc) and may ask the OS for one byte. Since you already know that you want `file.length()` bytes, there is no reason for not using the other more efficient forms.

Comment: thanx a lot for the reasons. it occured to me that i can just use BufferedReader. I'm somewhat confident that the reasons you mentioned (network, implementation, OS, etc) won't apply if I use BufferedReader. But please elaborate more at the last paragraph you wrote. are you saying that no loop is needed since i want to read the whole file?

Comment: In the last paragraph I was pointing out the difference between `read()` and `read(byte[],int,int)`, since you posted both codes in your question. 

I wouldn't be confident on undocumented behavior of a third-party library, because things may break someday/somewhere, and it is too high a price for saving a few lines. (Of course, you can play those tricks if you are writing a quick example, but try to avoid them in actual production code).

Comment: I added a reference to DataInputStream, which reads the complete stream into a byte array.

Comment: i want to insert unicode control characters in specific points. the prb is that all read methods give me an array of fixed size so i can't extend it. my only choice is to use input.read() which will return the byte i read. but u said that read slows my performance down. so what can i do? ur readFully won't work which u realized as soon as u read the purpose of my app. btw, whats the diff between them and the 2 read methods? same parameters, same array tht gets bytes saved. at least with read, i get int back so i can use it as a check to make sure i read the whole file.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you are reading from a network socket, not from a file. In this case you don't have any information about the total amount of bytes in the stream. You would allocate a buffer of fixed size and read from the stream in a loop. During one iteration of the loop you can't expect there are *BUFFERSIZE* bytes available in the stream. So you would fill the buffer as much as possible and iterate again, until the buffer is full. This can be useful, if you have data blocks of fixed size, for example serialized object.

```
ArrayList<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

try {

    InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    int bytesRead;
    int off = 0;
    int len = 1024;

    while(true) {
        bytesRead = input.read(buffer, off, len);            

        if(bytesRead == len) {
                list.add(createMyObject(buffer));
                // reset variables
                off = 0;
                len = 1024;
                continue;
        }

        if(bytesRead == -1) break;

        // buffer is not full, adjust size
        off += bytesRead;
        len -= bytesRead;
    }

} catch(IOException io) {
    // stream was closed
}
```

ps. Code is not tested and should only point out, how this function can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You specify the amount of bytes to read because you might not want to read the entire file at once or maybe you couldn't or might not want to create a buffer as large as the file.

Comment: thanx but I should have been clear at the beginning. In both code blocks I was reading the entire file. That was my goal. I just didn't know why I the writer of the article was afraid that it wasn't going to be read in one go.